# Is CLLocation latitude equal to zero?

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview

How do I check to see if _mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude is equal to 0?

Latitude is a type of double `typedef double CLLocationDegrees;`

I've tried comparing it to 0, -0.000000, 0.000000 and 0.00 with no luck.

I've tried converting it to a string like this

```
NSLog(@" lat %@", ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", _mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude] == @"0.000000") ? @"yes" : @"NO" );
string  0.000000 
lat NO
```

but this doesn't work either.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why you want to check zero latitude ???

Comment: I found that _mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate often returns 0 for both lat/lng and I don't want my program to do anything if this happens.

Comment: initially all member variable are set to their default values.
That is what happening in your case.. if you want to find user location the first find it's location by Location manager or let the map find it. and I thing Simple comparison  of == 0.0 would be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would think the above answers would work but I ended up storing latitude/longitude as a float then normal comparisons worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

It's stored as a [double](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html) so simple numeric comparison should suffice:

```
if (coordinate.latitude == 0)
```

However, if you're dealing with real locations, it's highly unlikely that it is ever actually 0, so you may need to round the value first.

From comments it looks like you are assuming that a coordinate of 0,0 indicates an error with the location. This is not the case. If the coordinate is invalid, then the [`horizontalAccuracy` property will be negative](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html). This is the correct way to check for an invalid coordinate:

```
if (coordinate.horizontalAccuracy < 0)
```

Comment: When MKMapView has an error it sends back 0,0 for lat/lon so I want to prevent the map moving to the ocean.  It's really strange this doesn't work `if (_mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude  == 0 || _mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude == 0)`

Comment: That's the wrong way of checking. If the coordinate is invalid, the accuracy will be negative. 0,0 is a valid coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why but if I store a reference as a float it works as expected.

```
float lat = _mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude;
float lon = _mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude;  

if (lat == 0 || lon == 0) {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

using swift, but the same you can do with category's objective-c:

```
extension CLLocation {

    func isZero() -> Bool {
        return self.coordinate.latitude == 0.0 && self.coordinate.longitude == 0.0
    }

}
```